# Как исправить ошибку при расшифровке AES?

Tags: android, криптография, java

При расшифровке получаю ошибку.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Шифрую и расшифровываю так.

```
private static byte[] password = null; //  this.password = editText.getBytes();
static final byte[] ivBytes = {'6','g','6','o','d','a','0','u','4','n','w','i','6','9','i','j'};

public static byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception {
    byte[] clear = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(password);
    kgen.init(256, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

public static String decrypt(byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(password);
    kgen.init(256, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
    String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
    return decrypted;
}
```

Подскажите, как избавиться от ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка из-за OpenSSL начиная с android 4.2 и выше.

Проблема решается так.

```
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
```

Answer (score 2):

AES это алгоритм симметричного шифрования, то есть ключ для шифрования и дешифрования один и тот же. В вашем коде ключи шифровки и дешифровки не совпадают и генерируются каждый раз заново.

Видимо, это у вас такой know-how ))

Comment: Ошибка паддинга вряд ли из-за этого происходит

Comment: @Fike оч. глубокомысленно конечно :) Но надо все таки включать мозги и смотреть на исходные тексты, где чел черным по белому генерирует разные ключи для шифрования и дешифрования. После такого может быть все что угодно в том числе и ошибка выравнивания блоков (то бишь паддинг)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, он сам паддинг нигде не генерирует, с чего бы?

Comment: @Fike вы хоть знаете что такое паддинг? Паддинг это правило выравнивания блоков в блочных шифрах. В данном случае длина блока AES 256 бит, то есть если вы кодируете данные длиной некратной 256 битам, то необходимо данные удлинить чтобы получилось кратно 256 битам. ТС использует метод паддинга `PKCS5`. PKCS5 это тупое заполнение остатка блока байтами со значением равным количеству заполненных байтов. В данном случае после дешифровки очевидно алгоритм пытается выкинуть выравнивающие байты, а он не подчиняется заданному правилу - оттуда и выкидывается исключение.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, AES кодирует 128 бит. Ответ понял.

Comment: @Fike да будет вам известно, AES кодирует блоками длиной 128, 192 и 256 - в данном случае ТС использует 256 битовый AES

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, "For AES, NIST selected three members of the Rijndael family, each with a block size of 128 bits, but three different key lengths: 128, 192 and 256 bits"

Comment: @Fike упс - ты прав :) у AES фиксированная длина блока 128 бит, просто при каждой итерации используются различные мутации ключа

Answer (score 1):

В другом классе, создаешь экземпляр класса AES и в констркутор класса AES передаешь пароль с которым ты хочешь шифровать:

```
AES aes = ne AES("password");
aes.encrypt("text bal bla bla")
```

Ну и так же дешифрование.

```
public class AES {
Cipher ecipher;
Cipher dcipher;

/**
 * Input a string that will be md5 hashed to create the key.
 * 
 * @return void, cipher initialized
 */

public AES() {
    try {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(128);
        this.setupCrypto(kgen.generateKey());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public AES(String key) {
    SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(getMD5(key), "AES");
    this.setupCrypto(skey);
}

private void setupCrypto(SecretKey key) {
    // Create an 8-byte initialization vector
    byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06,
            0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };

    AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    try {
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // CBC requires an initialization vector
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Input is a string to encrypt.
 * 
 * @return a Hex string of the byte array
 */
public String encrypt(String plaintext) {
    try {
        byte[] ciphertext = ecipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return this.byteToHex(ciphertext);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

/**
 * Input encrypted String represented in HEX
 * 
 * @return a string decrypted in plain text
 */
public String decrypt(String hexCipherText) {
    try {
        String plaintext = new String(dcipher.doFinal(this
                .hexToByte(hexCipherText)), "UTF-8");
        return plaintext;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public String decrypt(byte[] ciphertext) {
    try {
        String plaintext = new String(dcipher.doFinal(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
        return plaintext;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private static byte[] getMD5(String input) {
    try {
        byte[] bytesOfMessage = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        return md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";

public static String byteToHex(byte[] raw) {
    if (raw == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);
    for (final byte b : raw) {
        hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)).append(
                HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}

public static byte[] hexToByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length();
    byte[] ba = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        ba[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character
                .digit(hexString.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return ba;
}
```

}